# Fail to submit spark job

Tags: apache-spark, solr, spark-submit

I am trying to run the Spark-solr [Twitter example](https://github.com/lucidworks/spark-solr/blob/master/docs/examples/twitter.adoc) with spark-solr-3.4.4-shaded.jar,

```
bin/spark-submit --master local[2]  \  --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dtwitter4j.oauth.consumerKey=?
-Dtwitter4j.oauth.consumerSecret=? -Dtwitter4j.oauth.accessToken=? -Dtwitter4j.oauth.accessTokenSecret=?" \  --class com.lucidworks.spark.SparkApp \  ./target/spark-solr-3.1.1-shaded.jar \  twitter-to-solr -zkHost localhost:9983 -collection socialdata
```

but it is failed and the following message is shown

```
INFO ContextHandler: Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@29182679{/metrics/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.SparkContext.jobProgressListener()Lorg/apache/spark/ui/jobs/JobProgressListener;
```

I can confirm the path for ./target/spark-solr-3.1.1-shaded.jar is correct.

I suspect there is something wrong in --class com.lucidworks.spark.SparkApp  (ClassPath), but I am not sure.

I am running on local mode and I change the parameters as instructed in the example.

Version:

- Spark 2.1.1
- Spark-solr 3.1.1
- Solr 6.6.0

Comment: What is your Spark Version?

Comment: @philantrovert Version info added to the question.